# Search for an NSView inside a NIB by string

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to write an application which should display some data. The data in question comes from a different module in our code (written in C, not ObjC), and for various reasons is identified by a string, not an integer or other form of constant. After the glue code, I have an incoming method on my AppDelegate like so:

```
-(void)newstringdata:(NSString*)data withLabel:(NSString*)label;
```

This method should always take the value of `data` and set it as the text for a particular label in the UI. The problem is, which label.

I could of course create an `NSDictionary` and fill it at run time with the possible values for the `label` parameter in the `newstringdata:withLabel:` method and references to outlets, but this seems somewhat ugly and inefficient; it requires me to maintain the outlets, the nib, *and* the `NSDictionary`-initializing code.

Instead, if possible, I would like to set a property in the interface designer somewhere, and then do a lookup in my `newstringdata:withLabel:` method based on the label which was passed which returns the `NSLabel`.

Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: How is that your design somehow depends on identifying views by label strings when you haven't figured out how to assign label strings to views or even if you can? That is, where is the caller of the method you showed getting its label strings in the first place? How has it determined that those label strings correspond to views? What is the set of possible label strings? Etc.

Comment: I'm getting data from another module which identifies the data by its name, which is a string. This isn't something I have control over; it's how I get the data.

Comment: Right, but that data has nothing to do with your views. I recommend that you store the data in a dictionary property of your controller. Then, bind the views to the controller, through that property, to the value that makes sense for the view, if any does. That is, invert the problem by having the views/bindings find the data, not finding views based on the data.

Comment: How can I bind a view to an element in a dictionary? Must've missed that. Also, it still requires me to maintain a dictionary in code, which is a second place for the label; that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: The dictionary would be exposed via a property on the controller. The keys of a dictionary are treated as property names (also known as keys) by Key-Value Coding, Key-Value Observing, and Bindings. So, you can use a key path through the dictionary property on the controller to the key in the dictionary. Like: bind to File's Owner, model key path `dataItems.foo`, where `dataItems` is the property exposing the dictionary and `foo` is one of the keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of label will never include a slash (/), backslash (\), or colon (:), you can use the identifier property of NSView.

In the xib, enter each label string as the NSTextViews's identifier (in the Identity tab, 3rd tab from left).

Then in your code, loop through all views and:

```
if ([aView.identifier isEqualToString:label])
  [aView setStringValue:data];
```

Comment: This works, provided I verify that the aView objects I'm looping over actually implement the NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification protocol, which only the toplevel ones do; if I call "subviews" on the window and (recursively) its subviews, eventually you'll get at an NSView which doesn't.

Comment: Ok, then change the first line to:  if ([aView isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]] && [aView.identifier isEqualToString:label])